# Access intranet web page from a smart DVD player on the same intranet

Tags: html, media-player, intranet

Is there a way to access my intranet-based HTML catalog of DVD/Bluray titles using the dumbed-down browser on my intranet-attached Samsung H6500 player?  FWIW, the player's browser can access internet URL's just fine.

The Samsung browser does not seem to like html addresses of the form `HTTP://xxxx/` (which works OK on all my locally attached PCs).

My guess is the browser wants to see a url address of the form x.y.z.

Comment: What prevents you from navigating to your catalog's IP address using the browser on your DVD player?

Comment: The player's browser goes not like addresses of the form http://mylocalname/  .

Comment: That is probably because you do not have a DNS server for name resolution for these addresses. Try navigating to the IP address instead.

Comment: I've tried that before with no luck. I'll give it another try now.

Comment: FWIW:  The router seems to have hooks for private DNS names.  I'm a bit reluctant to start monkeying with this in case I break something I can't fix.